# LANCZOS interpolation in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, opencl, gpu, lanczos

Is it possible to implement LANCZOS interpolation on the GPU in OpenGL for android or would you say it is a task for OpenCL?

Time performance and device support are important issues.

Best regards,
David

Comment: Anyone? I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

[AMDs fidelityFX SR](https://gist.github.com/agyild/82219c545228d70c5604f865ce0b0ce5) uses a clamped lanczos kernel, this implementation for the mpv android port uses OpenGL ES.